# Windows 7 Integration in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-7

I'm trying to add Jumplist support to my app, but I can only find the source code of libaries to do this in C#, I can't find any dlls anywhere. So where can I get one?

Or am I totally wrong and how do add the new windows 7 features in vb net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the C# source to compile the libraries and then use them from VB.NET.

I assume you're looking for the [Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)? This should work just fine for you once compiled. Alternatively you could download the binaries for [this Taskbar library](http://windows7taskbarext.codeplex.com/) if it meets your needs (although it doesn't look like jump lists are done yet).

Comment: +1 for truth.  There's nothing stopping you from grabbing the c# project and throwing it into your solution.  It's not like you're planning to modify the API code pack, so you never really even have to look at it.  Just throw it in there and forget it exists.

Comment: I am using the express version which means I going to have download the c# IDE, I was trying avoid that. Is there any reason why there isn't just a compiled Dll to download?

Comment: It's easier not to bother keeping the binaries up-to-date. :)

Anyway, I would just get the C# Express download over with as there are bound to be more libraries you'll need it for.

Comment: I downloaded Visual C# express and compiled it. Now I am wondering how I can make an item on a jumplist that will not open a file but change something in the program, like in Live messenger there is the option to change the status(which isn't opening a new file/window)